# Docker-Squash command not working

Tags: docker, docker-compose

We are using docker-squash to squash images and we are facing 2 problems:

1. When trying to load the image using `docker load -i squashed.tar`, it returns the following:

   `Loaded image ID: sha256:e2be970be8222d5ab47d5c3633d437f86a5481d33df81dae00eb9ae0eeaeec00`

   However, upon firing docker images command, the image file doesn't show up!
2. We tried loading the docker file on other system and it says:

   `open /apps/docker/tmp/docker-import-734929610/0e0c7d7d5f7843e27756caa197f1ff2de3f7afb0890271b4a1fd95dd4c7bcaaa/layer.tar: no such file or directory`

Can squashed images not be run on other system or are we missing something?

Please help!